# Destroy action error: param not found: link

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, controller, destroy

I am building a mock up of reddit. When on my show view that displays the link & title I submit I have included an option(link) to destroy the submission.

When I click on the destroy I get:

```
ActionController::ParameterMissing in LinksController#destroy
param not found: link
```

on line:

```
params.require(:link).permit(:url, :title)
```

This is my full Links controller:

```
class LinksController < ApplicationController

    def index
      @link = Link.all
    end

    def show
      @link = Link.find(params[:id])
    end

    def new
      @link = Link.new
    end

    def create
      @link = Link.new(link_params)
        if @link.save
            redirect_to @link 
        else
            render action: 'new'
        end
    end

    def destroy
      @link = Link.find()
      if @link.destroy
        redirect_to index: 'action'
      else
        render show: 'action'
      end
    end


private
    def link_params
      params.require(:link).permit(:url, :title)
    end


end
```

This is my show view:

```
<h1> This is the show view </h1>


        <%= @link.title %>
        <%= @link.url %>
        <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_link_path(@link) %>\
        <%= link_to 'Destroy', (@link), method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
```

I'm really confused, have tried multiple things but can't get it to work. How can i fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you permit is missing :id and your destroy is missing params[:id] in the find clause.

Comment: This makes sense but now I am getting an error that states: "Couldn't find Link with id=11" or whatever the id it was for that particular link object.

Comment: Please double check in "rails console" those Link.find(...) statements.

Comment: What could this help me with? I'm a bit confused how to the results i get from the console could help me find the solution in this particular case.

Comment: Simply as step to narrow down the problem. When index views loads confirm the existence of the ids in the view with the console. Then invoke the delete. I frankly don't see how this happen. Maybe also look in logs, is it called twice, the first time it works, then the second time it fails. Just some guess work. Impossible to tell from distance. If the problem persists put it in a public github repository for review.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is:

```
def destroy
  @link = Link.find()
  ...
```

You need something like:

```
def destroy
  @link = Link.find(params[:id])
```

What's happening is that your **Destroy** link is sending a DELETE request to some URL like /link/23 with 23 being `params[:id]`.  You need to find the appropriate Link object by using `Link.find(params[id])` before you destroy it (similar to how you would in `show`).

Comment: This makes sense but now I am getting an error that states: "Couldn't find Link with id=11" or whatever the id it was for that particular link object.